# How can I connect an NVIDIA GeForce GT 330 to multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, nvidia-geforce

My video card has displayport & DVI-I. [I used this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bto1Q.jpg). I have:

- DVI-I to VGA (*Currently use this to connect Acer monitor*)
- Bizlink (Active Display Port to DVI-D) Cable. [View](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sapphire-44000-02-40R-Active-Display-Cable/dp/B00433C5Y4/ref=pd_cp_computers_1/280-1776905-6102842)
- DL-DVI-D to VGA adapter
- First display: Acer G225 HQ (VGA & DVI-D port)
- Second display: Dell 19 inch monitor (VGA port)

I want to use dual monitor. But I'm connecting video card to bizlink, DVI to DVI, and Dell monitor.

My video card can support multimonitor. [Geforce GT 330 Review](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_330_us.html)

How can I connect a second monitor?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: (Also, I will decline from editing this for readability because I'm not sure I've understood everything correctly :/)

Comment: Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it is confusing, but it sounds like you're trying to connect the Dell monitor via VGA, through a DVI-D adapter, through a DisplayPort adapter, to the DisplayPort connector on the card.  **This will not work because DVI-D is digital only**.  You need an active digital-to-analog converter somewhere along the line, that's what an adapter like that is intended to be used in conjunction with.  I'd just buy a DisplayPort to VGA converter (which generally don't need external power beyond what the DisplayPort provides itself, which is a nice bonus).

Comment: If my assumptions here are incorrect, please clarify.

Comment: i'm buying DVI to DVI (DL-DVI-D) cable to connect successfully. Now 1. DisplayPort to DVI converter,DVI to DVI cable,Acer monitor. 2. DVI to VGA converter,VGA cable, Dell monitor.